# Get String from value folder to class android

Tags: android, xml

I want to use a particular string found in the Values folder into normal classes. This is for my localization process with different languages.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) method on a `Context` (such as an `Activity`), specifying the key in this form: `R.string.you_key`

If you need to get a String outside of an Activity, like in a helper class or something, just make sure you pass in a reference to a context.

Answer (score 1):

Access the value by calling getString(R.string.your_string);

Ex.

```
String myValue = getString(R.string.your_string);
```

obviously replace "your_string" with the actual name you gave the string